# How to instantiate a list of classes using for loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

How can I instantiate objects from a list of different classes, each defined in a different module? Something like:

`a.py`:

```
class a():
    def __init__():
        print('a called')
```

`b.py`:

```
class b():
    def __init__():
        print('b called')
```

`main.py`

```
import a
import b

classes = ['a', 'b']

for class in classes:
    class = class()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you know all of the classes when you write the program (i.e. you're not trying to discover them dynamically at runtime), you can put the creation inside a list literal:

```
from a import a
from b import b

objects = [a(), b()]
```

If you're getting some list of classes from somewhere, then it's as simple as looping over that list and calling each class.

```
import a
import b

classes = [a.a, b.b]
objects = [cls() for cls in classes]
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the classes need to be referenced by a list of strings? You could do:

```
classes = [a.a, b.b]
for cls in classes:
    class_instance = cls()
```

Answer (score 0):

in case a User enters classnames, you need to process strings, like in your initial example with your definitions of classnames in a list of strings. In this case, use `eval(classname)` to get the constructor/init of your class.

```
from a import a
from b import b
classnames = ["a", "b"]
instances = [eval(n)() for n in classnames]
```

PS: you forgot the self in your **init**-definitions, which causes problems as such an error uccurs: `__init__()takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`